# CakePHP soft deleted data still showing up in model associations

Tags: model-view-controller, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, soft-delete

I am using the [SoftDeletableBehavior](https://github.com/evilbloodydemon/cakephp-softdeletable2) for my addresses model.

This sets it so when you delete an address it doesnt really delete it, instead sets a `deleted` column in the database to 1.

This also changes your query in the `beforeFind` function of the Address model to only pull entries where `deleted != 1`

This works when I am viewing addresses via the addresses controller like `/addresses/show/43`.

However my `Users` controller `hasMany` addresses. So when I am in the users controller and I call `$this->find('first');` To get the user, I also get the associated addresses. I am expecting this to NOT give me the (softly) deleted addresses but it DOES. The beforeFilter on the Address Model is never called either.

What is the right way to handle this?

---

### Update.

Apparently when I do this:

```
$data = $this->User->find('first',array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $id),'recursive' => 2));
```

I have a `$data['User]` array and a `$data['Address]` array (along with others).

But this does not use the beforeFind filter in the Address Model. So I get the wrong data.

But if I do this:

```
$data = $this->User->find('first',array('conditions' => array('User.id' => $id),'recursive' => 2));
$data['Address'] = $this->User->Address->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('user_id'=>$id)));
```

Then it *does* use the beforeFind filter on the Address model and returns the right data.

(Of course in a different format `[Address][0][id]` vs `[Address][0][Address][id]`)

**What I do not understand is if the associated data thats pulled does not use its own model to find its data, then whats the point? Isn't this one of the main purposes of MVC?**

Maybe I just don't understand? Or I am missing something?

Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you put this condition in your association?

```
<?php

class User extends AppModel {
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Address' => array(
            'conditions' => array('NOT' => array('Address.deleted' => '1')),
        )
    );
}

?>
```

Comment: +1 This does fix my current situation, but I still do not understand why it doesn't use its own model which already does this in the beforeFind filter. Maybe I should ask that as a seperate question tho. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would add a condition to the find query for users

$this->Users->find->('all',array('conditions'=>array('Address.deleted !='=>'1')));

(haven't tested the code for exact syntax, but this is the general idea)

Comment: This give me this error: `SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'Address.deleted' in 'where clause'` Not sure why, I do have a deleted column on the addresses table.

Comment: Is your debug mode higher than 0?  If it is, grab the query from the query log and paste it here please.

Comment: Here is the Query: `SELECT User.id, User.first_name, User.last_name, User.password, User.email, User.role, WishList.id, WishList.user_id FROM users AS User LEFT JOIN wish_lists AS WishList ON (WishList.user_id = User.id)  WHERE User.id = 4 AND Address.deleted != 1    LIMIT 1` It doesnt look like its selected from the addresses table. Not sure how it gets the data but on my user model I have `var $hasMany = 'Address';` and on the addresses table I have `user_id`

Comment: Are you using the containable behavior?

Comment: @amy no I am not, should I be?

Comment: Containable is a great tool because it helps you reduce query size when you don't need to pull out all the related models.  I was just trying to make sure you hadn't accidentally excluded Addresses in the above query.

Answer (score 0):

When you use $this->User->find(...) and include Addresses, you will only see the User model's callbacks fire, because that is the model you are using to drive the find.

This is why you have to use extra conditions in your User model's associations to filter out the soft-deleted Addresses.

If the Address model's callbacks were fired during every find on the User model when recursion scope included Addresses, you'd have no control as to when to include the soft-deleted Addresses and would risk clashes in functionality and param manipulation by those callbacks. Not to mention the serious performance impact this could have.